# Hash to string with given character set

Tags: r, hash

The usual hash-functions, e.g. from `digest` create hex output. I want to create a hash with character from a given set, e.g `[a-z,0-9]`; no strong cryptographic security is required.

Using `base64encode` on a hashed string comes close, but the character set is fixed in that function.

Comment: On my system, `digest("anton")` gives "1b17325d9c286f0187efcfbd7de6b74e" which is hex. I want a shorter string that in addition avoids some easily confused characters like "l" and O/0 for easier mnemonics.

Comment: Of course, sorry. my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ugly div/mod manipulation for an arbitrary character table, so I decided to use a 32 character table without l 0, O

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

static const std::string base32_chars = "abcdefghijkmnpqrstuvwxyz23456789";

// [[Rcpp::export]]
String encode32(uint32_t hash_int, int length = 7)
{
  String res;
  std::ostringstream oss;
  if (length > 7 || length < 1) 
    length = 7;
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    oss << base32_chars[hash_int & 31];
    hash_int = hash_int >> 5;
  }
  res = oss.str();
  return res;
}

/*** R
print(encode32(digest::digest2int("Hellod")))
*/
```